# Unable to login with google in blazor maui

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, maui, maui-blazor

Hello Devs I'm Developing an application which will run on mobile, desktop and web the thing where i got stuck in is Google Login in blazor maui i've developed web application which is working fine with google login please go through my code and let me know if you have any idea how can i achieve same thing in blazor maui.

1. The problem is i'm unable to use IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor in maui blazor
2. IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor returns null while trying to achieve in maui blazor(mobile,desktop)

```
@using System.Security.Claims
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor
@inject HttpClient Http
@if (User.Identity.Name != null)
{
    <img src="@Avatar" />
    <b>You are logged in as: @GivenName @Surname</b>
    <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary"
   href="/Auth/Logout"
   target="_top">Logout</a>
}
else
{
    <a class="ml-md-auto btn btn-primary"
   href="/Auth/Login"
   target="_top">Login</a>
}
@code {
    private ClaimsPrincipal User;
    private string GivenName;
    private string Surname;
    private string Avatar;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        try
        {
            
            **//Getting Null here in maui blazor**
            User = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;  
            // Try to get the GivenName
            var givenName =
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User
                .FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName);
            if (givenName != null)
            {
                GivenName = givenName.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                GivenName = User.Identity.Name;
            }
            // Try to get the Surname
            var surname =
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User
                .FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname);
            if (surname != null)
            {
                Surname = surname.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Surname = "";
            }
            // Try to get Avatar
            var avatar =
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User
            .FindFirst("urn:google:image");
            if (avatar != null)
            {

                Avatar = avatar.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Avatar = "";
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use  **HttpContextAccessor** to get the current User in blazor for security reasons. As an alternative, you could try using **AuthenticationStateProvider** to get the current User info.

```
private async Task GetClaimsPrincipalData()
{
    var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authState.User;
...
}
```

For more information , you could refer to [Blazor and shared state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-and-shared-state) and [AuthenticationStateProvider service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#authenticationstateprovider-service).